# Would 2020 election decide whether Mr. Pompeo stay in power or not?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, china

Mike Pompeo currently serves as United States Secretary of State. Does the upcoming election decide whether Mr. Pompeo stays in power or not?

Comment: Biden has hinted that if he is elected he will consider filling some Cabinet positions with Republicans. I strongly suspect that keeping Mike Pompeo and William Barr (amongst others) in their positions is a possibility that Biden is not considering. Their jobs will end at noon on January 20, assuming Biden is elected.

Comment: @DavidHammen Biden would do well to put in some qualified Reps.  It would go a long way towards starting a healing process.  However, anyone *still* serving under this administration is by definition contaminated by association, the principled ones have left or been fired.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica There are a few Trump-appointed administrators who have done a good job. One example (and the only example I can think of) is that there are a number of people working on space exploration who, regardless of party affiliation, would not mind seeing or would even prefer to see Jim Bridenstine kept on as NASA administrator.

Comment: @DavidHammen Yes, I suspect that "Don't use chemical weapons against protestors so that the president can hold a Bible upside down for a photo op" is on Biden's list of qualifications.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Mike Pompeo is US Secretary of State. In the USA this is a Cabinet position, appointed by the President and a partisan role.  If Donald Trump were to lose the election then a new Cabinet and new Secretary of State would be appointed by the new President.

Joe Biden could choose Pompeo as his Secretary of State, but given Pompeo's critisim of Biden, there absolutely no chance of this happening.  Biden will pick a Secretary of State that is he can work closely with.

Answer (score 5):

Pompeo had a better reputation coming into this administration than he has now.  More principled fellows have left it.  Doubt this will be a case of someone keeping a cabinet position under a new administration [like Obama did with some Bush appointees](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/obama-keeps-several-bush-picks-in-top-jobs/).